# Query XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML doc in this format

```
<User 1>
<sub>text1</sub>
<sub>text2</sub>
</User 1>

<User 2>
<sub>text3</sub>
<sub>text4</sub>
</User 2>

<User 3>
<sub>text2</sub>
<sub>text3</sub>
</User 3>

<User 4>
<sub>text1</sub>
<sub>text4</sub>
</User 4>
```

Here all user nodes have sub nodes with a value of text1, text2 etc depending on their requirement. I want to display these values, how can i do this? Can I create XML like this and display the values? When i tried it said no property exists with name "sub".

[edit]
I have the root element,I just didn't mention it before.
Before your answer I was using the code below to get one value from a user

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("usermachine.xml"));
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "sub";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "userid";
    DropDownList2.DataSource = ds;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

If i want to display the one or many values inside (sub) of a particular user in a `DropDownList` what should i do?

Comment: what are you doing so far? [Ask]

Comment: I mentioned what I have done so far ..I dont see error in my code because when there is only one <sub> in a particular user it gives me the required output...but my requiement is that  a user might have 1 or many <sub>... when i use more than one it shows me error!!

Comment: @Valamas-AUS-This is only XML part of my asp.net in C# project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using valid XML

firstly you need to have a root node and the user ID should be in an attribute like this

```
<Users>
   <User id="1">
      <sub>text1</sub>
      <sub>text2</sub>
   </User>

   <User id="2">
      <sub>text3</sub>
      <sub>text4</sub>
   </User>

   <User id="3">
      <sub>text2</sub>
      <sub>text3</sub>
   </User>

   <User id="4">
      <sub>text1</sub>
      <sub>text4</sub>
  </User>
</Users>
```

Once your XML is formatted properly, you could query it like so

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\test.xml");
var user = doc.Descendants("User").Where(x=>x.Attribute("id").Value =="1")
                                  .Select(x=>x.Value);
```

To answer your added question

something along these lines would make it useful for mapping to a dropdown

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\test.xml");
var user = doc.Descendants("User").Select(x=>new {UserId = x.Attribute("id").Value, Sub=x.Element("sub").Value});

DropDownList1.DataSource = "user";
DropDownList1.DataTextField= "UserId";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Sub";
```

If you want multiple items on dropdown for each user, one for every sub you could use this

```
var result = res.Descendants("sub")
                .Select(x => new {UserId = x.Parent.Attribute("id").Value, Sub = x.Value});
```